# Append divs based on selection of dropdown list item

Tags: html, append, dropdown

I'm struggling to complete one of my client requirement. Partially, I've completed it but not able to achieve my goal.

I googled alot but wouldn't be able to findout the one which I'm looking for.

I'm very new to angularjs and learning day by day so please apologies me if you found my question very simple

Question:

I need to appened multiple divs on each other (stack form) but based on dropdown list selection.

My partial working code is:

HTML Code:

```
<select id="shipping_selector" name="existing_us_ID">
 <option value="0">SELECT</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<div id="data_1">
Div one
<input type="text">
</div>

<div id="data_2" >Div two<input type="text"></div>
<div id="data_3">Div three<input type="text"></div>
```

AngularJs Code:

```
$("#shipping_selector").change(function() {
$('#data_1,#data_2, #data_3').hide();


    var id = $(this).val(); 


    $("#data_" + id).show();


}).change();
```

The above working code will only show one div at a time. e.g. if I've selected the 'One' then it will show corresponding div and if I selected the 'Two' from dropdown list then it will show the corresponding div and remove the previous div.

My requirement is two append second div to first and so on based on dropdown selection.

Timelines are very short for me so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide the `div` through `css` initially and display them on `onChange` like this

```js
$("#shipping_selector").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $("#data_" + id).show();
}).change();
```

```css
#data_1,#data_2,#data_3{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="shipping_selector" name="existing_us_ID">
 <option value="0">SELECT</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<div id="data_1">
  Div one
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div id="data_2">Div two<input type="text"></div>
<div id="data_3">Div three<input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: impresive answer. I never thought it can be handled only by css. can you guide on one more option? I want one option (suppose One) want to add multiple times.

Comment: @AnubhaS If you want to add it multiple time you have to create it dynamically and append it in js rather than creating it initially